# Is there a way to change the icon of the PrintPreview dialog in MsChart?

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm using C# 4.0 and MsCharts within Visual Studio 2010. When I execute

```
MyPlotChart.Printing.PrintPreview();
```

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.printingmanager.printpreview ) It works as intended, but the Print Preview dialog shows the default icon. Is there a way to use my own icon, please? Like what I would do with PrintPreviewDialog.Icon (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.icon.aspx )

Thanks.

Comment: MSChart uses the native version of Print Priview and doesn't provide access to an icon.  If you want to use the built-in print-preview you're stuck...  If you *really* want to have a different icon, you'll have to implement your own print-preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I wrote a hack for this. I added a forms.timer that I enable right before calling PrintPreview(). Then I locate the form in Application.OpenForms and set the icon.

```
    private void printPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PrintPreviewIcon != null)
        {
            PrintPreviewTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        PlotChart.Printing.PrintPreview();
    }

    private void PrintPreviewTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f is PrintPreviewDialog)
            {
                f.Icon = PrintPreviewIcon;
                PrintPreviewTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? Just set the Icon property of the printer preview dialog!

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson, He is changing the icon of print preview dialog. He uses this workaround because the instance of print preview dialog is not available directly in Form. Note that this is the print preview of some custom control, so he probably does not have control over the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

My answer, just set the icon property:

```
    public DialogResult ShowPrintPreview(float zoomFactor = 1F)
    {
        _nPageNumber = 1;
        _bPrintSel = false; 

        _previewDlg.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = zoomFactor;
        _previewDlg.Size = new Size(1200, 800);
        _previewDlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        _previewDlg.Icon = **PrintPreviewIcon**;
        return _previewDlg.ShowDialog(this);
    }

    public Icon PrintPreviewIcon { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Long time later but that help me to find the solution :

```
(printPreviewToolStripMenuItem as Form).Icon = Properties.Resources.MonIcon;
```